# Phonegap Start app with link to web forced in webview

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to force my iOS Phonegap app to point to a web address instead of the www/index.html which it's linked to by default is this possible and where do I go to configure this.

Answer (score 2):

Thats not really what Phonegap is for. Websites that are packaged as apps are generally rejected from the App store by Apple.

Create a custom local site (using Jquery mobile or the like) and pull content from the web using XML or JSON.

Comment: However I did try it and it works now. Thanks for the advice.